# Can you add reinforcement learning to convolutional neural network to improve image classification?

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I am quite new to machine and deep learning. My doubt is How to add reinforcement learning to an image classifier developed using conventional neural network to better its performance over time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I believe Google AutoML does things like this.

The problem with doing this on your own is, reinforcement learning works by doing thousands, if not millions of trials.

A convolutional neural network is trained on hundreds and sometimes thousands of epochs, with thousands of images each.

For every iteration the reinforcement learning model completes, it has to re-train the entire convolutional neural network, which takes a lot of time.  So if you are ok with re-training your cnn thousands of times, the reinforcement learning approach might work.